# How to solve the following print question?

Tags: tcl

I came across this the command below in TCL:

```
Set inst mem[7:0]
```

Whis is the syntax about and how to print each indices using for loop separately?

Comment: Important: was that *exactly* what you saw, or were there any extra quotation marks or curly braces or backslashes?

Comment: The command quoted doesn't actually look like Tcl at all.

Answer (score 1):

I work in chip design and use Synopsys design tools.  Synopsys uses a Tcl interface for their tools.  The Synopsys Tcl interpreter has some extra things that tclsh does not have.  One is that the square bracket can contain an integer or range of integers to represent bussed nets or pins (just like in Verilog), and the interpreter will not try to execute the string inside the brackets as a command.

As a result, in Synopsys Tcl, `set inst mem[7:0]` is valid.  But it's simply a single variable named `inst` with the string value `mem[7:0]`.

Comment: How to print the following resilt

Comment: How to print the following  "t:i:mem[0) t:i:mem[1] and so on

Comment: In your example, the `mem[7:0]` is literally a string assigned to a SINGLE variable named `inst`.

If you actually have a variable which is a COLLECTION (this is a Synopsys thing), then you can do `foreach_in_collection net $nets {puts [get_attribute $net name]}`

Until you understand the difference between a string and a collection, there's nothing else I can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote exactly is not standard Tcl. Standard Tcl would be more like one of these:

```
set inst mem\[7:0\]
```

```
set inst {mem[7:0]}
```

The differences here are the all-lower-case `set` (a basic Tcl command to write to a variable) and the quoting of `[7:0]` so that it is not interpreted as a command substitution. In theory you could define an `unknown` handler to make it so that you don't need to do that, but that'd be pretty gross and slow.

The other possibility is that this is some sort of little language, which might be seen overall like:

```
doTheThing {
    Set inst mem[7:0]
}
```

The `doTheThing` command here is suspending the normal parsing rules (or rather it is never invoking them) and can do absolutely anything with what's between the braces. People have used this to embed C, Fortran, HTML, and so on in Tcl; it's a totally legitimate technique (though obviously the command doing the trickery is not going to be literally called `doTheThing`). However, if that's going on then there's no way to say what's going on *from the perspective of general Tcl.* It's library- or application-specific.

---

It looks like it is something to do with taking slices (the low 8 bits) of a data bus that will be used to define an instruction to execute, but that's just a guess based on having read custom hardware definitions a few times.